# Is it idiomatic to say "Let's have a check."? Or should I say "Let's check it." or "Let's check."

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, idiomatic-language

Is it idiomatic to say **"Let's have a check"**, just like we say **"Let's have a look",** or **"Let's have a listen.**"?

If not, should I say: **Let's check** or **Let's check it.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is grammatically correct, it is used, it is informal, it is understandable, but I wouldn't say that it is idiomatic.

According to this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=let%27s%20have%20a%20look%2C%20let%27s%20have%20a%20check&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clet%20%27s%20have%20a%20look%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clet%20%27s%20have%20a%20check%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Clet%20%27s%20have%20a%20look%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clet%20%27s%20have%20a%20check%3B%2Cc0), "Let's have a look" is used about five hundred times as often as "Let's have a check", and even that over-estimates the occurrences of the "check" version, as many of the actual instances are partial matches, like "let's have a check-up".

Either "Let's check" or "Let's check it" are OK: which is better depends on the context. The former is about 300 times as common as "Let's have a check".

Answer (score 0):

It is correct.

It's common to precede 'check' with an adjective

People often say *"Let's have a quick check"*, or *"Let's do a proper check"*, *"Let's do a full check"*

Answer (score -1):

It's OK, but *very informal* to the point some would consider it slang.

It also has a nuance of condescension, so when I read that sentence, I picture a parent or doctor speaking to a child, or an IT support person talking to someone with a really simple tech problem.

It's not nearly as common or natural as "let's have a look/listen".